# Hacking/cloning sklearn to support pruning Decision Trees?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, decision-tree, pruning

I wanted to create a decision tree and then prune it in python. However, sklearn does not support pruning by itself.
With an internet search, I found this:
https://github.com/sgenoud/scikit-learn/blob/4a75a4aaebd45e864e28cfca897121d1199e41d9/sklearn/tree/tree.py

But I don't know how to use the file. I tried:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
import tree

clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
iris = load_iris()

clf = clf.fit(iris.data, iris.target)
```

But I get the error ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package.
Is that not how I import? Do I need to save the files in a different way? Thank you.

Comment: Which sklearn branch do you use? the original one? the one forked by sgenoud? Did you download the tree-python file from the fork into your workspace? Without these information, I cannot tell you where your import goes wrong.

Comment: The one forked by sgenoud. I downloaded just tree.py. I don't know what you mean by workspace. I have my iris file (as described above) and tree.py saved in the same folder, C:\Users\Beck\Anaconda\machine_learning

Comment: If you really want to use [sgenoud's 7-year-old fork](https://github.com/sgenoud/scikit-learn/tree/4a75a4aaebd45e864e28cfca897121d1199e41d9) of [scikit-learn](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn) from back in 2012, `git clone` on the **base directory on the repo**, don't just try to copy/clone individual files.

Comment: ...But that idea sounds misconceived: you can get shallower/pruned trees by changing parameters to get early stopping [`DecisionTreeClassifier` parameters max_depth, min_samples, min_samples_leaf, min_impurity_decrease, min_impurity_split](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html#sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier). See the doc and play around with the parameters, they do what you're asking for.

Answer (score 1):

Scikit-learn version 0.22 introduced pruning in DecisionTreeClassifier. A new hyperparameter called `ccp_alpha` lets you calibrate the amount of pruning. See the documentation [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/tree/plot_cost_complexity_pruning.html#).

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use [sgenoud's 7-year-old fork](https://github.com/sgenoud/scikit-learn/tree/4a75a4aaebd45e864e28cfca897121d1199e41d9) of [scikit-learn](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn) from back in 2012, `git clone` on the base directory of the repo, don't just try to copy/clone individual files (of course you'll be losing any improvements/fixes since 2012; way back on [v 0.12](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/whats_new/older_versions.html#version-0-11))

But that idea sounds misconceived: **you can get shallower/pruned trees by changing parameters to get early stopping [`DecisionTreeClassifier` parameters max_depth, min_samples, min_samples_leaf, min_impurity_decrease, min_impurity_split](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html#sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier)**. See the doc and play around with the parameters, they do what you're asking for. I've done ML for >10 years and never once seen a need to hack the DT source. There are tons of good reasons not to do this and no good reasons to.

(And if you try to play with the DecisionTreeClassifier parameters and still can't get what you want, post a reproducible code example here using an open-source dataset like iris etc.)

Comment: This is the best answer here, but if anyone wants to suggest an improvement, suggest it. In general cloning stale 7-year-old experimental forks of obsolete versions is a bad idea. Especially in this case since it was unnecessary in the first place, `DecisionTreeClassifier` gives you lots of knobs to tweak to get pruned trees.

Answer (score -1):

In Python, Modules (=Packages in other languages) oftentimes define routines that are interdependent. In these cases, you cannot only download one .py file and put it into your Workspace (i.e. the directory where your sources are located). Instead, download the entire package into that folder, and import relatively, i.e. like this:

```
# a general import, should only be used if you are absolutely certain that there will be no namespace conflicts
from sklearn.tree.tree import * 
# a more "safe" way is to import the classes/functions you need explicitely
from sklearn.tree.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
```